# Problems with File reader

Tags: python, python-3.x

so this piece of code is meant to create a new file, file1.txt, and have it write inside the file this block under, and close it.

```
Summer
Break
Now
```

However, I am having problems with it entering the code. If I add commas to split them, it gives an error saying it can only take one argument. But, right now it is not printing anything.

```
f = open("file1.txt","w")
f.write("Summer\nBreak\nNow")
f.close()
```

Comment: That code does look correct to me. Are you sure you're not getting that content in `file1.txt`?

Comment: Yeah, I checked many times, I don't know why it isn't working haha,

Comment: To clarify, it's not _printing_ anything, or it's not _writing anything to the file_? Those are two different things in python.

Comment: I'm gonna guess the code ran and the file is somewhere other than where you expect it to be. The file will save in the directory you run the script from, unless you give the full path.

Comment: Yeah, I just realized what it was. Had a spelling error in the file name and it didn't match the name given in the code haha. Thanks again man